# Why my IconMenu react component have error? Warning: Unknown event handler property `onKeyboardFocus`. It will be ignored

Tags: reactjs

```
<div className="uk-flex">
    <form className="uk-search uk-search-default" onSubmit={e => e.preventDefault()}>
        <span className="uk-search-icon-flip" uk-search-icon=""/>
        <input defaultValue={searchText} className="uk-search-input" type="search" onKeyUp={this.setSearchText} placeholder="Поиск..."/>
    </form>
    <IconMenu
        onChange={this.onAccessTypeChange}
        style={{cursor: 'pointer'}}
        iconButtonElement={<i className="life-bi-icon life-bi-icon-plus-circle-small"/>}
        anchorOrigin={{horizontal: 'right', vertical: 'top'}}
        targetOrigin={{horizontal: 'right', vertical: 'top'}}
    >
        <MenuItem style={{fontSize: '12px', lineHeight: '30px', minHeight: '30px'}}
                            value="all"
                            onClick={this.showModalBimsCreateTab}
                            primaryText="Добавить вкладку"/>
        <MenuItem style={{fontSize: '12px', lineHeight: '30px', minHeight: '30px'}}
                            value="groups"
                            onClick={this.showModalBimsCreateBookmarkGroup}
                            primaryText="Добавить закладку"/>
        <MenuItem style={{fontSize: '12px', lineHeight: '30px', minHeight: '30px'}}
                            value="employees"
                            onClick={this.showModalBimsCreateBookmark}
                            primaryText="Добавить ссылку"/>
        <MenuItem style={{fontSize: '12px', lineHeight: '30px', minHeight: '30px'}}
                            value="employees"
                            className={!isNull(this.state.activeTab) && this.state.activeTab.name === 'Общее' || !isNull(this.state.activeTab) &&  this.state.activeTab.name === 'Инструкции' ? "hidden" : null}
                            onClick={this.showModalBimsUpdate}
                            primaryText="Редактировать"/>
        {/*<MenuItem style={{fontSize: '12px', lineHeight: '30px', minHeight: '30px'}}
                            value="employees"
                            onClick={this.showModalBimsEdit}
                            primaryText="Редактировать"/>*/}
    </IconMenu>
</div>
```

I already read another topics about this error but can't find what div component i need to remove for solve this problem.
In iconButtonElement i need to use not  ??? i tested another component but also have this error (`iconButtonElement={<IconButton><MoreVertIcon/></IconButton>}`)

Comment: Possibly because the iconButtonElement property actually expects a 'button', and not an 'i'.

Comment: @rrd i tried to use iconButtonElement={<IconButton><MoreVertIcon/></IconButton>} but it doesnt helped to me